# JS doesn't detected when I change Option, Variable keeps undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to generate an automatic email address, based on user change.
The point is to print the domain name, the rest is working fine.

here is my issue, I'm getting the element ID, if the element ID the Var x takes the values of an other var depending on the selection however, X keeps undefined.

I think that somehow it doesn't detect when I select an other option.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

```
<select name="select"   id="selecto">

                        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
                            <option value="value1" id="1">SEE</option>
                            <option value="value2" id = "2">Guillebert</option>
                            <option value="value3" id = "3">Saelen</option>
                            <option value="value4" id ="4">SEE Produktion</option>
                            <option value="value5" id ="5">TS-Industrie</option>
                            <option value="value6" id="6">Schliesing</option>
                        </select>

                        <script type="text/javascript">

    var a = "@groupesee.com";
    var b = "@guillebert.fr";
    var c = "@saelen.fr"; 
    var d = "@see-produktion.net;"
    var e = "@ts-industrie.de";
    var g = "@schliesing.net";
    var x;

if(document.getElementById('selecto').value == "value1") {
     x = a;
     alert("Success");
}
</script>
```

For some reason, and I do not understand why, the var x, is keeping null even if I select the value1 in my form.

```
<script>
    $("#field1, #field2").keyup(function(){
update();
});

function update() {
  $("#result").val($('#field1').val().substr(0,1).toLowerCase() + $('#field2').val().toLowerCase()+x);
}
    </script>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: u have mssing here some of your codes.

Comment: What do u mean ?

Comment: whatever u shown in picture, does it in the code ?

Comment: Yep, it's just a form with an Input. Everything is working fine, except that when i'm trying to assign a value to x, depending on the select value. I do not understand, why x doesn't take the value of a. It takes tha value of "  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>"

Comment: put entire js code in single `<script> .. </script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code *just runs* as it loads. It only checks the value of the select element *once* (as the page loads and the script element is executed).

If you want it to run every time the select element is changed, then you need to say so.

1. Put your code in a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
2. [Find the select element in the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
3. [Listen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the value to [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) and call the function

Comment: Thank your very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix, using the  in the Update function. :)  Tyvm @Quentin

```
    function update() {
      var a = "@groupesee.com";
    var b = "@guillebert.fr";
    var c = "@saelen.fr"; 
    var d = "@see-produktion.net;"
    var e = "@ts-industrie.de";
    var g = "@schliesing.net";
    var x;

     var elt = document.getElementById(selecto);
     if(document.getElementById('selecto').value == "value1") {
     x = a;

   } if(document.getElementById('selecto').value == "value2") {
     x = b;
}
    if(document.getElementById('selecto').value == "value3") {
     x = c;
}
 if(document.getElementById('selecto').value == "value4") {
     x = c;
}
 if(document.getElementById('selecto').value == "value5") {
     x = c;
}
 if(document.getElementById('selecto').value == "value6") {
     x = c;
}

  $("#result").val($('#field1').val().substr(0,1).toLowerCase() + $('#field2').val().toLowerCase()+x);
}
```